# The solver configuration does not exist error in grails optaplanner

Tags: java, grails, drools, file-not-found, optaplanner

I am trying to run the cloud balancing example as in optaplanner site [here](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html). I have placed the cloudBalancingSolverConfig.xml file in web-app/xmls directory. Here is my code of the save action of CloudBalanceDomainController:

```
def save() {
        def serveletContext = ServletContextHolder.servletContext
        def storagePath = serveletContext.getRealPath( "/" )

        String temp=storagePath+"xmls"+File.separator+"cloudBalancingSolverConfig.xml"
        File f=new File(temp)
        if(f.exists())
            println "file exists!"
        SolverFactory solverFactory=new XmlSolverFactory(temp)
        Solver solver=solverFactory.buildSolver()
        CloudBalance unsolvedCloudBalance=new CloudBalancingGenerator().createCloudBalance(params.computers,params.processes)
        solver.setPlanningProblem(unsolvedCloudBalance);
        solver.solve()
        CloudBalance solvedCloudBalance = (CloudBalance) solver.getBestSolution()
           render(view: "create", model: [cloudBalanceDomainInstance: cloudBalanceDomainInstance])
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'cloudBalanceDomain.label', default: 'CloudBalanceDomain'), cloudBalanceDomainInstance.id])
        render "${getToDisplayString(solvedCloudBalance)}"
        //redirect(action: "show", showStr: getToDisplayString(solvedCloudBalance))
    }
```

On running, it returns following exception:

```
Executing action [save] of controller [optaplannergrails.CloudBalanceDomainController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:222) ~[grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.java) ~[plugin-classes/:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:183) ~[grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.java) ~[plugin-classes/:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:116) ~[grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.java) ~[plugin-classes/:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:72) ~[grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:328) ~[grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789) [spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195) [plugin-classes/:na]
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.simple.MemoryPageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(MemoryPageFragmentCachingFilter.java) [plugin-classes/:na]
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63) [plugin-classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:314) [grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:279) [grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:270) [grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:221) [grails-plugin-url-mappings-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPageFilter.java:200) [grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:151) [grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.grails.plugin.resource.DevModeSanityFilter.doFilter(DevModeSanityFilter.groovy:44) [plugin-classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69) [grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:66) [grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.30.jar:7.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(MixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:73) ~[grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.java) ~[plugin-classes/:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:334) ~[grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.java) ~[plugin-classes/:na]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:217) ~[grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    ... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243) ~[springloaded-core-1.1.1.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(MixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:69) ~[grails-web-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    ... 80 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The solver configuration (C:\Users\rahulserver\IdeaProjects\OptaPlannerGrails\web-app\xmls\cloudBalancingSolverConfig.xml) does not exist.
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.XmlSolverFactory.configure(XmlSolverFactory.java:65) ~[optaplanner-core-6.0.0.CR5.jar:6.0.0.CR5]
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.XmlSolverFactory.<init>(XmlSolverFactory.java:51) ~[optaplanner-core-6.0.0.CR5.jar:6.0.0.CR5]
    at optaplannergrails.CloudBalanceDomainController.save(CloudBalanceDomainController.groovy:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195) [plugin-classes/:na]
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63) [plugin-classes/:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

It says that `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The solver configuration (C:\Users\....\IdeaProjects\OptaPlannerGrails\web-app\xmls\cloudBalancingSolverConfig.xml) does not exist.`
However, surprising thing is that `f.exists()` returns true, hence the file is being found. So what may be causing this error?

**EDIT:**
`f.canRead()` and `f.canWrite()` also returns true.Hence the file has both read and write permissions. Although it does not need to write to the file here.

Comment: permissions???? (total guess hence the comment)

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for the solver configuration in the classpath with `getClass().getResource("...")`. Files or URL's are not supported that way (but you can mimic this by building your own `KieBase` base upon a file).

So if your file is in `C:\Users\....\IdeaProjects\OptaPlannerGrails\src\main\resources\org\foo\bar\solverConfig.xml` in a maven project, you 'd get it with `/org/foo/bar/solverConfig.xml` because `src/main/resources` is part of the java classpath in maven. If `web-app\xmls\` is part of the classpath (which it probably isn't because it's part of the war resources probably) just `cloudBalancingSolverConfig.xml` would work.

Anyway, you probably want to make sure your xml ends up in `yourWebApp.war!/WEB-INF/classes/org/foo/bar/solverConfig.xml` and load it with  `/org/foo/bar/solverConfig.xml`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the bandwidth (nor the expertise) to maintain a grails (or rubyOnRails or scala's lift) version of the optaplanner-examples.jar (which is swing based). I already struggle to keep the optaplanner-webexamples.war (JSP based) up to date, and it only has 2 of the examples. If someone wrote such a public grails example (I 've heard about other non-public implementations already), I am happy to link it from the blog etc :)

Comment: In any case, optaplanner itself doesn't care whether it runs in grails/rubyOnRails/lift/jsp/jsf/gwt/swing/...: as long as it's a valid JVM, it's works :) I will add a section in the manual "integration with web frameworks" to better explain the fact that scoreDrl expects for a classpath resource, not a web resource or a file. If you think the other ways are useful too, file a jira.

Comment: I dont get you.Grails projects are different from maven. Do you want to say that the xml file must be in classpath?

Answer (score 0):

If other answers do not help (like in my case when packaging solverConfig.xml into a Spring Boot application) then this small change might help you out:

```
SolverFactory.<PlanningSolution<BendableScore>>createFromXmlInputStream(
                    getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("org/foo/bar/solverConfig.xml"))
```